# MYSQL is not null, not skipping results that are null

Tags: mysql, null

I thought I had this query built correctly to skip results that are NULL yet the NULL rows still show:

```
SELECT post_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_payment_meta' 
                THEN meta_value 
                END) as 'DeliveryDate' 
FROM postmeta 
WHERE 'DeliveryDate' IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY post_id
```

What is being missed where it is still showing the NULL results?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Single quote chars `'` are used to quote string literals, to quote column name you must use backtick char. `WHERE 'DeliveryDate' IS NOT NULL` checks does the string literal `'DeliveryDate'` is not null which is always TRUE - i.e. this condition do nothing.
2. Output column name cannot be used in WHERE - it not exists when WHERE clause is executed (formally, of course). If you need a condition which uses output column you must place it to HAVING clause.

So:

```sql
SELECT post_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_payment_meta' 
                THEN meta_value 
                END) as `DeliveryDate`
FROM postmeta 
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING `DeliveryDate` IS NOT NULL
```

From the other side - you need `post_id` with `meta_key = '_payment_meta'` - so you may filter rows before grouping and do simple

```sql
SELECT post_id,
       MAX(meta_value) as `DeliveryDate`
FROM postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_payment_meta' 
GROUP BY post_id
```

This query will do the same.

If `(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)` is defined as UNIQUE (which is logical if the table stores only actual data, not values history) then the query may be simplified to

```sql
SELECT post_id,
       meta_value as `DeliveryDate`
FROM postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_payment_meta'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it!

Answer (score 1):

'DeliveryDate' in the WHERE clause is being interpreted as a string literal ... and as such IS NOT NULL

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer combined with the answer above solved this